# can i get the scores of the individual players live from espncricinfo using node.js cherrio parser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the live scores of the individual players and the scores from espncricinfo but i am unable to retrieve it :

i am only getting some of the datas but not the scores , since the data is coming dynamically that's the reason why i cant get these datas.

My node.js code is as follows:

```
 app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
url = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league
              -2014/engine/match/733985.html';

request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('td.batsman-name').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                console.log("Hi Entered");
                console.log(data.text());
        })
     }
```

But i am getting no results.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the site you connect to dynamically loads the data you are trying to scrape, so you are most likely using cheerio on html that is incomplete. You might figure out the url that they are using to load their data with information, and scrape that instead.